# Remove n elements from start of a list in pandas column, where n is the value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have the following DataFrame:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]]
b = [3,1,2]
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(a,b), columns = ['a', 'b'])
```

df:

```
                      a  b
0       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  3
1      [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]  1
2  [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]  2
```

How can I remove the first n elements from each list in column `a`, where n is the value in column `b`.

The result I would expect for the above df is:

```
                      a  b
0                [4, 5]  3
1         [7, 8, 9, 10]  1
2          [13, 14, 15]  2
```

I imagine the answer revolves around using `.apply()` and a `lambda` function, but I cannot get my head around this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["a"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["a"][x["b"] :], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
               a  b
0         [4, 5]  3
1  [7, 8, 9, 10]  1
2   [13, 14, 15]  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df['a'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['a'][row['b']:], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
               a    b
0          [4, 5]   3
1   [7, 8, 9, 10]   1
2    [13, 14, 15]   2
```